# How to update selected Tab in TabView

Tags: swiftui

Anyone know why didSet doesn't work anymore (ios16 Xcode 12) on TabView?

```swift
    @State var selected: Int {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.activeTab = selected  <<-- never gets called
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            
            Text("food")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("food", systemImage: "bolt.fill")
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            Text("wtr")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("water", systemImage: "drop.fill")
                }
                .tag(1)
}
```

this seems to be a functional workaround

```swift
    
    @State var selected: Int

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            
            Text("food")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("food", systemImage: "bolt.fill")
                }
                .tag(0)
                .onAppear{ UserDefaults.activeTab = 0 }
            
            Text("wtr")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("water", systemImage: "drop.fill")
                }
                .tag(1)
                .onAppear{ UserDefaults.activeTab = 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you cannot use `didSet` for `State` variables. Instead, you would use the `onChange(of:perform:)` method. This method gets called when the specified variable's value changes.

In your case, your view would look like this:

```
@State var selected: Int

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selected) {
        Text("food")
            .tabItem {
                Label("food", systemImage: "bolt.fill")
            }
            .tag(0)
        
        Text("wtr")
            .tabItem {
                Label("water", systemImage: "drop.fill")
            }
            .tag(1)
    }
    .onChange(of: selected) { newValue in
        UserDefaults.activeTab = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: that's helpful thank you!